# Why does Excel give me the wrong number of characters when I use LEN?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am new at excel but when I was working on a spreadsheet where I needed to use `LEN` to know the number of characters of a date and time in a cell, it gave me a completely different number which resulted in faulty results in my analysis.
What should I do to fix that?

I looked up online for some solutions and I tried counting the zeros. It wasn't counting or the space it might not include as a valid character, but it still came out wrong. The only way it would function the way it should is when I used `LEN` on a cell that had letter and not numbers.

Comment: Please post your actual problem value and the formula you're trying to apply. Note that `LEN()` is designed for text, and dates in Excel are actually numbers though formatting displays it as a date.

Comment: As @bugdrown mentioned above, the string representation of your date you see is controlled by cell settings, but doesn't actually change the underlying data in your date cell (or the output of the `LEN` function). If you want a cell that contains a string representation of the date, you may want to add another column that formats the date using something like `TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`. Calling `LEN` against that cell will give you what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

[image]

You can see what is getting counted. So, organise your data as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel function `len` is a string function. so it can only be applied to strings. Numerical datatypes such as integers or floating point values cannot directly be analysed with it. Dates and time data are internally stored as floating point values in Excel, its output is just formatted so it gives date and time information.

Now when you want to get the length of a date and time cell content, you must convert it to text using Excel's `text` function.

Now if you had supplied some examples or code, this answer could have been a bit more specific. ;-)